# Как правильно перегрузить функцию

Tags: c++, функции

Есть две функции. 1-ая сортирует список по `char`, а 2-ая по `int`, но у них разные имена. Подскажите как правильно перегрузить функции.

```
//sort by char
void List::SortByChar()
{
    Listnode *current = head; //вспомогательный указатель.  
    Listnode *next = nullptr; //вспомогательный указатель.  

    if (head == NULL)
        return;
    else {
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            next = current->next;

            do {                
                if (strcmp(current->name, next->name) > 0) {
                std::swap(current->name, next->name);
                std::swap(current->age, next->age);
                }
                next = next->next;
            } while (next != NULL);
            current = current->next;
        }
    }       
}

//sort by int
void List::sortByInt()
{
    Listnode *current = head; //вспомогательный указатель.  
    Listnode *next = nullptr; //вспомогательный указатель.  

    if (head == NULL)
        return;
    else {
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            next = current->next;

            do {                    
                if (current->age > next->age) {
                    std::swap(current->name, next->name);
                    std::swap(current->age, next->age);
                }
                next = next->next;
            } while (next != NULL);
            current = current->next;
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас все совершенно одинаково кроме одной строчки. Я бы добавил функцию сравнения, которую передавал единой функции сортировки в качестве параметра.

Типа

```
static bool Listnode::cmpname(Listnode*a, Listnode*b)
{
    return strcmp(a->name, b->name) > 0;
}

static bool Listnode::cmpage(Listnode*a, Listnode*b)
{
    return a->age > b->age;
}

typedef bool (*cmpfunc)(Listnode*, Listnode*);

void List::SortBy(cmpfunc)
{
    Listnode *current = head; //вспомогательный указатель.  
    Listnode *next = nullptr; //вспомогательный указатель.  

    if (head == NULL)
        return;
    else {
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            next = current->next;

            do {                
                if (cmpfunc(current,name)) {
                std::swap(current->name, next->name);
                std::swap(current->age, next->age);
                }
                next = next->next;
            } while (next != NULL);
            current = current->next;
        }
    }       
}
```

Аналог `SortByInt` при этом -

```
list.SortBy(cmpage);
```

а `SortByChar` -

```
list.SortBy(cmpname);
```

Более того, в `List::SortBy()` можно передавать лямбда-выражения, скажем

```
list.SortBy([](Listnode*a, Listnode*b){ return a->age > b->age; });
```

Comment: как я понял сделать единую функцию с параметром, а что я должен сравнить?

Comment: Сравнивает этот параметр - это **функция** сравнения.

Comment: а какие параметры я должен написать в функцию `sortBy` что-то я не понимаю. Для студента это как-то трудновато

Comment: Вы просто передаете функцию, которая будет вызвана для сравнения. Я написал в ответе, и как написать такие функции, и как их передать в метод сортировки. Функция сравнивает два Listnode так, как это нужно вам - по имени, возрасту, в любом порядке. Вы просто говорите - когда надо будет сравнить два узла - вызови для этого ту функцию, что я указал.

Comment: понял, спасибо за помощь и понимаине

Comment: За понимание - это спасибо вам :) Если бы не поняли, было бы куда хуже...

Answer (score 0):

Я решил поупражняться в написании кода на C++, и вот что у меня получилось в контексте вашего вопроса. Я опирался на ваш предыдущий вопрос, где вы привели определение структуры списка и некоторых его методов.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <utility>
#include <initializer_list>

class List
{
public:
    enum SortType { SortByName, SortByAge };
    typedef std::pair<const char *, unsigned int> Human;

public:
    List() = default;
    List(const List &) = delete;
    List & operator =(const List &) = delete;
    ~List()
    {
        while (head)
        {
            Person *tmp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete[] tmp->name;
            delete tmp;
        }
    }

    void push(const char *name, unsigned int age)
    {
        push({ name, age });
    }

    void push(const Human &h )
    {
        char *s = new char[std::strlen(h.first) + 1];
        std::strcpy(s, h.first);
        head = new Person{ s, h.second, head };
    }

    std::ostream & show(std::ostream &os = std::cout) const
    {
        for (Person *current = head; current; current = current->next)
        {
            os << current->name << ' ' << current->age << std::endl;
        }

        return os;
    }

    void sort(SortType type = SortByName)
    {
        bool ( *order_by[2] )( const Human &, const Human & ) =
        {

            []( const Human &h1, const Human &h2)
            {
                int res = std::strcmp(h1.first, h2.first);
                return res < 0 || (res == 0 && h1.second < h2.second);
            },
            [](const Human &h1, const Human &h2)
            {
                int res = std::strcmp(h1.first, h2.first);
                return h1.second < h2.second || 
                       ( h1.second == h2.second && res < 0);
            }
        };

        if (type != SortByAge) type = SortByName;

        for (Person *current = head; current; current = current->next)
        {
            for (Person *next = current->next; next; next = next->next)
            {
                if (order_by[type](Human(next->name, next->age),
                    Human(current->name, current->age)))
                {
                    std::swap(current->name, next->name);
                    std::swap(current->age, next->age);
                }
            }
        }
    }

private:
    struct Person
    {
        const char *name;
        unsigned int age;
        Person *next;
    };

    Person *head = nullptr;
};

int main()
{
    List lst;

    for (const auto &h : std::initializer_list<List::Human>( 
    { 
        { "Petr", 21 }, 
        { "Ann", 26 }, 
        { "Bob", 24 },
        { "Kate", 24 }
    } ) )
    {
        lst.push(h);
    }

    lst.show() << std::endl;

    lst.sort();

    lst.show() << std::endl;

    lst.sort(List::SortByAge);

    lst.show() << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль выглядит следующим образом:

```
Kate 24
Bob 24
Ann 26
Petr 21

Ann 26
Bob 24
Kate 24
Petr 21

Petr 21
Bob 24
Kate 24
Ann 26
```